# Why does Postgres to throw a unique constraint violation on an empty table?

Tags: database, postgresql, sails.js, waterline

Ok, so I have, what seems to me like a very weird issue. I have a Postgres table created with the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE message
(
  message text,
  author integer,
  thread integer,
  id serial NOT NULL,
  "createdAt" timestamp with time zone,
  "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone,
  CONSTRAINT message_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
  ALTER TABLE message
  OWNER TO glenselle;
```

I'm using Sails.js (which uses Waterline ORM) to save a message model to the database. Mind you, in the process of trying to isolate the problem I began dropping the table every time I try saved a new record and the behavior is always the same. The ORM is doing some associations for me to associate the author with a user model and the thread with a thread model. Anyway, when I attempt to save a record, I first get this:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "message_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "message" ("message", "author", "thread", "id", "createdAt", "updatedAt") values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING *
```

So this should be really easy to understand. There's already a row in the table with an id of 1 which is why the "message_pkey" constraint is violated. But the ironic thing is that there is no data! So my question is this, what could be happening that causes Postgres to throw a unique constraint violation if the table has absolutely no data in it (it was just dropped and recreated it with the SQL I posted above)?

Here's what I'm running to create the model:

```
create: function(req, res) {
    var self = this;

    Thread.create({}, function(err, newThread) {
        if(err) return console.log(err);

        Message.create({message: req.body.conversation[0].message}, function(err, newMessage) {
            if(err) return console.log(err);
            // This returns an array of user ids
            sails.controllers.thread.parseUserIds(req.body.participants, req.user, function(idList) {

                // First, associate the message with the author
                newMessage.author = req.user.id;
                newMessage.save(function(err, savedMessage) {
                    if(err) return console.log(err);

                    // First, associate the participants with the thread
                    newThread.participants.add(idList);

                    // Next, associate the message with the thread
                    newThread.conversation.add(savedMessage);

                    newThread.save(function(err, savedThread) {
                        if(err) return console.log(err);

                        console.log('The thread looks to have been saved. Check it out!');
                        return res.json(savedThread);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: Is there anything in your `config/bootstrap.js` file?

Comment: Nope...except for cb(); which I assume is just the default callback like next() in Express?

Comment: After you get the error, can you look in the db and see if there are any records in it?

Comment: Enable `log_statement = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf` and see if there might be *two* statements being run, with the second failing. Or a single multi-row insert.

Comment: And/or post the code you're using to save the record...

Comment: @ScottGress Yes, after it throws the error there is data still being saved. It puts in the id of 1 (which doesn't seem to make sense) it adds the message text and the two dates (createdAt and updatedAt) but it leaves the author and thread columns blank.

Comment: @Criag Ringer I have Postgres logging set to verbose (don't know if that's the same as 'all') and I only see an error, a detail message and the statement like I posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to pass a model instance to `newThread.conversation.add`, which is a shortcut for "create and add".  To add an existing instance to a collection, you need to pass its ID. Change the line to:

```
newThread.conversation.add(savedMessage.id);
```

and it should work.

A couple of other points:

1. Rather than accessing a controller method directly via `sails.controllers.thread.parseUserIds`, you might consider moving that code into a *service* (in the `/api/services`) folder.  Services are automatically globalized by Sails and can be accessed from any controller.
2. If you're attempting to pass in an array of IDs to `newThread.participants.add`, that will end up failing as well.  You'll need to loop through the array and call `add` with each individual element.

Support for IDs (and passing existing instance objects) will likely be added in the near future, but we didn't want to let bells and whistles delay the release of baseline associations support.  Make those adjustments and your code should work now!